# Big Cartel - Add a description text in each of my categories

Tags: html, css, text, insert, bigcartel

I have a problem that I cannot solve on my BigCartel site for several weeks.

I would like to add a descriptive text for each of my categories. There is currently no block of text where I could enter a description in the page under the name of my category and I would like the text to be different for each of my categories.

I think in photo it will be simpler ... (here is a picture attached).

[image]

Thank you for help me :)

Best

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am now looking to do this same exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing to do is to make sure you have the theme api imported
Second: This escape here will display your JSON array for all categories:

```
{{ categories.all }}
```

I placed this in the bottom of the layout html. Although I'm sure there are some other spots that would work just fine. 
Using that array, loop through it to dynamically create an input box for each category and place it wherever you would like

The next question here, is how you would save and maintain the 'description' or whatever it is you want for that particular category to stay. As I assume you probably want a unique value for each category. Going to be working on just this thing tonight or tomorrow. So I'll check back and update my answer once I've got that part figured out.

On a side note, if your categories aren't going to be changing all the type, you could create just a series of your own variables that match the category and hard-code "write" the value for the text box as it pertains to that category.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is different for different themes but I am using the “Roadie” theme and this is what I did:

1. Go to the Advanced Settings
2. Go to Products
3. [where to put the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkDzV.jpg)

The code is:

{% if page.full_url contains 'your/permalink' %}
The category info you want
{% endif %}

If your page name is “Tops” your permalink is “/category/tops”
You can put multiples of these for each of your categories right under each other. So just copy and paste and change the info in it for the different categories.